# How do I set a dynamic max input date?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set a user input value that lets you choose a date within a range. I am able to set a minimum date, but I do not know how to set a maximum date. Basically I want a user to be able to select a date anytime between today, and 2 months from now, keeping that range all the time. I don't know how to set up that dynamically changing max value though.

```
<input type= "date" name="Date">
$Date = ($_POST['Date']);
if (strtotime($Date) < mktime(0,0,0)){
            echo "Sorry, you can not pick that date!";
```

I want it to look something like...

```
if (strtotime($Date) < mktime(0,0,0) && strtotime($Date) > "Enter code here"){
            echo "Sorry, you can not pick that date!";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
<input type="date" name="Date" min="<?= date('Y-m-d'); ?>" max="<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+60 days')); ?>">
```

Then after you can validate the selected data in PHP like this:

```
if($_POST['Date'] >= date('Y-m-d') && $_POST['Date'] <= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+60 days'))){
    echo 'Good date';
}else{
    echo 'Bad date';
}
```

Comment: always use <?php echo  instead of <?=

Comment: @DrJManish <? =?> is equal to <? php echo?>

Comment: What @DrJManish is trying to say is: The problem is that you can't guarantee that you'll have <?= if you're trying to write code that could work in a wider range of PHP versions. But there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: yes... it is true... but using <?php is better...that is my point

Comment: _...do I need to update my answer?..._ You could mention the issue with the shorthand. But your answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Maxime, don't listen opinion-based comments. Your original code was absolutely correct. There's no any "better" when it comes to the taste.